# what's the meaning of format mean for spcific column in pb?

Tags: powerbuilder

after i execute one line code like this:
sz_format = this.Describe( "#1.Format" )

this is what sz_format return:

sz_format =""[general]if(1=2,",'[general]')""

what's the meeaning of sz_format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the 'General' keyword in formats means you want PowerBuilder to determine the appropriate format for a number, i.e., you don't want to force a specific numeric format on the column.

You example sz_format has two parts.  The first is "[general]". This is the format of the column put in place when the datawindow object was created.  The second portion is an expression assigned to the column (this can be done when the dwo is created or via a Modify statement).  It is a boolean expression which always is false "if(1=2...".
In a boolean expression the format is

`if(<condition>,<action if true>,<action if false>)`

So in your example if 1=2 was ever true then there is no format.  If 1=2 is false the format is "[general]".

Why the format is as you have shown is something unknown to me.